# Updating values in another column based on certain date conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a dataframe which has datetime datatype columns which DOB and another column Age , and here i want to update Age column to 0 for the DOB junk values i..e in DOB column there are dates which are  01-01-1900 date time .Hence dates above and equal to 1900 i want to update in the Age column as 0 .

DOB: datetime64[ns]
Age: Object
Tried below codes , however the expected result isn't correct

Tried below codes , not sure what is going wrong

```
df['Age'].mask(df["DOB"]>="01-01-1900" ,'0', inplace=True)
```

or another code tried

```
df['Age'] = np.where(df["DOB"]>="01-01-1900", 0,
df['DOB'])
```

With the above codes all the DOB dates are getting incorrectly updated alng with Age column as 0 for incorrect dates.

The update of age to 0 should be done only for dates WITH 1900 in DOB

Original dataframe:

```
DOB          AGE
2004-05-17   18
1900-01-01   141
1900-02-01   135
```

Expected output:

```
DOB          AGE
2004-05-17   18
1900-01-01   0
1900-02-01   0
```

Answer (score 2):

If need compare datetime column vy another dates use format `YYYY-MM-DD` - default datetime format in python:

```
#if need compare only year for less or equal 1900
df['AGE'] = np.where(df["DOB"].dt.year <= 1900, 0, df['AGE'])

df['AGE'] = np.where(df["DOB"] < '1901-01-01', 0, df['AGE'])

df.loc[df["DOB"].dt.year.le(1900), 'AGE'] = 0

print (df)
         DOB  AGE
0 2004-05-17   18
1 1900-01-01    0
2 1900-02-01    0
```

---

```
#if need compare datetime need YYYY-MM-DD format
df['AGE'] = np.where(df["DOB"].eq('1900-01-01'), 0, df['AGE'])
print (df)
         DOB  AGE
0 2004-05-17   18
1 1900-01-01    0
2 1900-02-01  135
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that the comparison of the date in the DOB column with the string "01-01-1900" is not working as expected because the DOB column is of datetime type and the comparison is done with a string. In addition, your second code snippet is replacing the values in the Age column with the DOB column, which is not the desired behavior.

To update the Age column to 0 for dates greater than or equal to 1900 in the DOB column, you can use the following code:

```
df.loc[df['DOB'] >= '1900-01-01', 'Age'] = 0
```

This code will update the Age column to 0 for all rows where the DOB column is greater than or equal to "1900-01-01". The `loc` method is used to select the rows that meet the condition and update the Age column.

Make sure that the DOB column is of datetime type before running the code. You can convert the column to datetime using `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])`.

I hope this helps!